# Styling ul with first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists

I'm sure this shouldn't be difficult to solve but I can't get my styling for a ul to work (trying different things, it either works for one, or none at all) and I'm about to tear my hair out. What have I missed?

https://jsfiddle.net/5cuuq8rq/

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="?page=home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="?page=couriers">Couriers</a></li>
   <li><a href="?page=reviews">Reviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="?page=retailers">Retailers</a></li>
   <li><a href="?page=about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{   
font-size:18px; 
font-weight: bold;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}

.nav li{
display:inline; 
}

.nav a{
width: 144px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(256,256,256), rgb(175,175,175));
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(256,256,256), rgb(175,175,175));
background:         linear-gradient(rgb(256,256,256), rgb(175,175,175));
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
 }


.nav li > a:first-child {
border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of this

```
.nav li > a:first-child {
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

use it

```
.nav li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are selecting the first **a** element which is always going to be true since there is only one **a** element in each of your **li** elements. Instead, you should select the first **li** element and then target the **a** element nested in that **li**. For example, your CSS should look like this:

```
.nav li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Check out this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5cuuq8rq/1/

Answer (score 1):

if you use nth-child(some number)
you can specify what li you will style by giving it a number, 1 for first and so on:) good luck.

```
.nav li:nth-child(1) > a {
     border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```